# Как удалить определенный элемент из подсписков в списке?

Tags: python, list

Помогите сделать внутренний for loop который удалит элемент из всех саблистов в листе.
Код который я написал ниже удаляет только элемент в первом саблисте, как сделать так чтобы он не останавливался когда найдет элемент который нужно удалить?
Важная деталь: нужно оставить поиск по индексам чтобы можно было использовать .pop()

```
my_list = [['Sasha', 'Kolya', 'Vasya'], ['Vasya', 'Kolya', 'Sasha'], ['Kolya', 'Vasya', 'Sasha']]

for sublist in my_list:
        for i in range(len(sublist)):
            if sublist[i] == 'Vasya':
                sublist.pop(i)
```

Comment: По-русски это называется "список".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так устроит?

```
my_list = [[elem for elem in obj if elem != 'Vasya'] for obj in my_list]
```

вариант №2:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i].remove('Vasya')
```

Comment: а в коде который я написал можно что-то отредактировать чтобы получилось то что нужно? по заданию нужно в таком же стиле как в вопросе написать

Comment: добавил второй вариант, он то устроит?

Comment: идеально, благодарю